# What's the largest known range of natural temperature variations of human inhabited Earth across history?

Tags: temperature, ice-age, natural-conditions

I was reading about the ice age when temperature dropped 11 celsius degrees in relation with our current temperature. Then I found another article which says the temperature fluctuated 15 degree celsius.
 [Scientists throw light on mysterious ice age temperature jumps](https://phys.org/news/2017-06-scientists-mysterious-ice-age-temperature.html) 
Speaking of times where Earth was inhabited by humans, and speaking about the average temperature of the planet, what's the largest known range of natural temperature variations the Earth had? Are those 11/15 degrees celsius the largest natural range of temperature changes Earth experienced or were there times Earth was hotter than now, or colder than the ice age, making the range of natural temperatures existing in human inhabited Earth larger than that?

Comment: is it possible for you to put in a link to where you get the 11 celsius number from? just to get some background information to your question.

Comment: @trondhansen I couldnt find the one I mentioned, but I found another which states the temperature fluctuated 15 degree celsius.